# Determining the interval where the solution is valid

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the initial value problem

$$
y' = \frac{1+3x^2}{3y^2-6y} 
$$
given y(0)= 1

I have solved this and I got $y^3-3y^2 -x-x^3=-2$. How would I got about finding the interval in which the solution is valid? I know I should solve for y first but I'm having issues doing that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424035/largest-open-interval-the-solution-is-defined?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19495/determine-the-interval-in-which-the-solution-is-defined?rq=1) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $3y^2-6y\ne0$. Since $y(0)=1$, we know that $0<y<2$.

Put $y=0$ in $y^3-3y^2 -x-x^3=-2$, and we know $x=1$. Similarly, when $y=2$, we have $x=-1$.

Hence, $-1<x<1$ is the interval we want. However, it is not easy to solve for y. (See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E3-3y%5E2-x-x%5E3%2B2%3D0).)

Comment: Why did you take the derivative of the function that I found to get $3y^2-6y$

Comment: @Ayoshna When $3y^2-6y=0$, $y' = \frac{1+3x^2}{3y^2-6y}$ is not defined.